# How to handle signals on QRemoteObject?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtremoteobjects

I'm a bit new to `Qt`, after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112014/how-to-use-the-qremoteobject-class-to-share-data-between-processes/76142205#76142205) I'm trying to learn more about `QRemoteObject`, following the mentioned question, comments, and links, I tried to write a class to share data between processes.

Based on the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtremoteobjects-repc.html) I build this `.rep` file into the two processes:

```
class SharedObject
{
    SIGNAL(signalAPP1(QString text))
    SIGNAL(signalAPP2(QString text))
};
```

However, when I press `F2` on `APP1` it's not firing the lambda on `APP2`

```
   connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1, this, [](QString text) {
      qDebug() << "signalAPP1! text:" << text;
   });
```

The same thing happens when i press `F2` on `APP2`, it's not firing the lambda on `APP1`

```
   connect(sharedObject, &SharedObject::signalAPP2, this, [=](QString text)  {
      qDebug() << "signalAPP2! text:" << text;
   });
```

What i'm missing?

`app1.h`

```
#include "rep_sharedobject_source.h"

class SharedObject : public SharedObjectSource
{
    Q_OBJECT 
 public:
signals:
    void signalAPP1(QString text);
    void signalAPP2(QString text);
};

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class APP1Class; };
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class APP1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SharedObject* sharedObject = nullptr;
    QRemoteObjectHost srcNode;
    Ui::APP1Class *ui;

    APP1(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::APP1Class())
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        sharedObject = new SharedObject();
        sharedObject->setObjectName("sharedObject");
        srcNode.setHostUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("local:sharedObject")));
        srcNode.enableRemoting(sharedObject);

        QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2), this);
        connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [=] {
            qDebug() << "emiting...";
            emit sharedObject->signalAPP1("hello from APP1");
        });

        connect(sharedObject, &SharedObject::signalAPP2, this, [=](QString text)  {
            qDebug() << "signalAPP2! text:" << text;
        });
    }
};
```

`app2.h`

```
#include "rep_sharedobject_replica.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class APP2Class; };
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class APP2 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Ui::APP2Class *ui;
    QSharedPointer<SharedObjectReplica> ptr;
    QRemoteObjectNode repNode;

    APP2(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::APP2Class())
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
 
        repNode.connectToNode(QUrl(QStringLiteral("local:sharedObject")));
        ptr.reset(repNode.acquire<SharedObjectReplica>());

        connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::initialized, this, [=]
        {
            qDebug() << "conected...";

            connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1, this, [](QString text) {
                qDebug() << "signalAPP1! text:" << text;
            });
        });  

        QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F2), this);
        connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [=] {
            QString str = "hello from APP2";
            emit ptr.data()->signalAPP2(str);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your problem with the code you provided and solved it.

First thing first: I find it strange your subclass of `QMainWindow` is what is in charge of publishing/retrieving the remove object, let alone do it in the constructor.

Now for your issue. According to my analysis, the replica fails to acquire a connection to the original object because you did not name it.
That is something I warned about in the other question you consulted and I believe you should have notice you never get to execute the lambda connected to the `SharedObjectReplica::initialized` signal that you expect. That was a big clue as to where exactly your code was not meeting your expectations.

In APP1, do, with a name:

```
srcNode.enableRemoting(sharedObject, QStringLiteral("MySharedObject"));
```

And the corresponding in APP2:

```
ptr.reset(repNode.acquire<SharedObjectReplica>(QStringLiteral("MySharedObject")));
```

Now that the replica is connected to the object, we need to address your `SharedObject` class. As you have defined a `SharedObjectSource` superclass from a `.rep` file, the signals `signalAPP1` and `signalAPP2` are already defined after compiling it.

`SharedObject::signalAPP1`/`SharedObject::signalAPP2` conflict with `SharedObjectSource::signalAPP1`/`SharedObjectSource::signalAPP1`, so remove them from `SharedObject`.

And finally, `signalAPP1` works as expected (but not `signalAPP2`).

The reason for that comes from a misunderstanding on your end: signals only flow from the server to the client.
Put another way: the client application can request the state of an object hosted on server (aka original object) to be changed but it makes no sense that the client application notifies the server said original object has changed.

- `signalAPP1` flows from the server to the client, so everything is good.
- `signalAPP2`, in your code, is designed to flow from the client to the server which, like I said, makes no sense.

The correct approach was to create a `Q_INVOKABLE` method on the server.

```cpp
class SharedObject : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
[...]
    Q_INVOKABLE void SharedObject::emitSignalAPP2(QString text) {
        emit signalAPP2(text);
    }
}
```

and in the `.rep` file, declare a slot:

```
SLOT(emitSignalAPP2(QString))
```

And finally, what you must connect to the `F2` key shortcut:

```
connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [=] {
    QString str = "hello from APP2";
    emit ptr.data()->signalAPP2(str);
    }
);
```

---

Final note:

This way of connecting signals on the client is IMO wrong:

```cpp
connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::initialized, this, [=]
    {
        qDebug() << "connected...";
        connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1, this, [](QString text) {
            qDebug() << "signalAPP1! text:" << text;
        }
    );
```

A `SharedObjectReplica` is a valid `QObject` so as long as you have a valid instance, you can create the connection **even** if `SharedObjectReplica::isInitialized()` returns false for that instance.
The consequence of waiting for the `&SharedObjectReplica::initialized` signal to be emitted is that if the server shuts down and then restarts, you will receive a new signal, therefore create a new connection. After that happens (and since you did not specify `Qt::UniqueConnection` on `&SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1`), your lambda is executed twice for every `signalAPP1` receives.
Then 3 times if the server restarts again, then 4 and so on.

The correct way to connect signals from a replica is to ignore whether or not the connection was established, i.e. simply do:

```cpp
connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1, this,
    [](QString text) {
        qDebug() << "signalAPP1! text:" << text;
    }
);
```

Comment: I have fixed the object name like your code on APP2 but when i emit the signalAPP1 from APP1 on APP2 its not receiving it

Comment: In APP1 i modified `srcNode.enableRemoting(sharedObject, QStringLiteral("MySharedObject"));` and then hit F2 on it, but APP2 doesnt fire its lambda `connect(ptr.data(), &SharedObjectReplica::signalAPP1, this, [](QString text) {          qDebug() << "signalAPP1! text:" << text; });`

Comment: So you never get the "connected" in the debug stream?

Comment: Yes, I do get it

Comment: And do you get the "emitting" in the debug stream of APP1?

Comment: yes i get the emitting

Comment: So the replica is connected to the original object, signalAPP1 is emitted from the original object but not transmitted to the replica, is that correct? You're sure that it's on APP1 that you click F2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253430/discussion-between-raja-and-atmo).